# Copy files from one to another in php not working

Tags: php, copy

Trying to `copy` files from one directory to another in `PHP`, but it is not copying.

My Code:

```
<?php
copy('lang.php', '../lang.php');  //lang.php
copy('db_doc.php', '../me/db.php'); //db.php
copy('vdb_doc.php', '../me/vdb.php'); //db.php
copy('db_log.php', '../dbconfig.php'); //dbconfig.php
copy('inser_sql.php', '../inser_sql.php'); //inser_sql.php

echo "Installation Successful! <a href='../'>Go Back</a>";
?>
```

Comment: So... any errors?

Comment: You can also try with `file_gets_content()` and `file_puts_content()`...

Comment: check folder permission also before call `copy()`

Comment: paste " if(!@copy('lang.php','../lang.php')){$errors= error_get_last();echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];} else {echo "File copied from remote!";}  " and see what the error is.

Comment: @RomalTandel I got permission error: `COPY ERROR: 2
copy(../lang.php): failed to open stream: Permission deniedInstallation Successful! Go Back`

Comment: change folder permission. to 755

Comment: @Scuzzy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411981/copy-files-from-one-to-another-in-php-not-working/47412133#comment81778232_47411981

Comment: @RomalTandel How? And where? At `.htaccess`?

Comment: go to file manager on cpanel there you can find permissions column in list of files

Comment: @RomalTandel The biggest issue is I don't have cpanel else it was easy. I just have hosting, and accessing my files through ftp

Comment: this will help http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: @RomalTandel I will be thankful if you give me the exact code, rather than syntax. And I want to set it for all the page and directory...

Comment: @YashParekh please have look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411981/copy-files-from-one-to-another-in-php-not-working/47412133?noredirect=1#comment81779904_47412133

Answer (score 0):

Error should be here :

1: Try to check `FOLDER PERMISSION` (How to play with Permission ? see http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php )

2: `Parent folder` does not exist (you are using `../`).

**How Copy() works :**

```
 bool copy ( string $source , string $dest [, resource $context ] )
```

Makes a copy of the file `source` to `dest`.

> If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.

**How to set Permission (Linux) ? :**

Go to your Linux Terminal and use command `sudo chmod 755 -R folder_name`, if you are using VPS/Dedicated. if you are using Shared Hosting simply go to `www` folder and set permission by following given steps using `UI`

Comment: I got permission error: `COPY ERROR: 2
copy(../lang.php): failed to open stream: Permission deniedInstallation Successful! Go Back`, so how to set permissions? By including `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @AkshayMandale see http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php `SET 0755` (security issue exist, but set to check `copy()`)

Comment: Simply go to parent folder (mostly in `public_html`) and set permission for all files in Folder, What Type of Web Hosting, you are using ?

Comment: So, how to set the permission?

Comment: So, I should write `chmod("htdocs", 0755);` in `htaccess` file?

Comment: have you shared hosting ?

Comment: Managing platform

Comment: go to your htdocs folder, there must be availability for changing permission, no need to update .htaccess

Answer (score -1):

```
1. Folder permission - so try to give that folder recursive permission.
2. Use 
bool copy ( string $source , string $dest [, resource $context ]) function
eg: $file = '/test1/example.txt'; 
$newfile = '/test2/example.txt';
if(!copy($file,$newfile)){
  echo "failed to copy $file";
}else{
  echo "copied $file into $newfile\n";
}

Refer this link as well - 
http://www.phpkida.com/php-tutorial/copy-multiple-files-from-one-folder-to-another-php/
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411981/copy-files-from-one-to-another-in-php-not-working#comment81778398_47412133