# Issues with copying files between two sites/accounts on server

Tags: php, linux, file, copy

I have a Linux Server that I have two sites/accounts set up on. I am working to migrate some of the information from site1 to site2 through a series of PHP scripts, however, I am began to run into some issues.

Here is my server set up:

- PHP Version: 5.5.38
- Apache: 2.4.41
- Site 1: /home/site1/public_html/
- Site 2: /home/site2/public_html/

When I attempt to copy files using this logic, I am greeted with this error:

```
//Create original file for future use
if (copy($site1.'/uploads/v2n62l6v.jpg', $site2.'/uploads/v2n62l6v.jpg')) {
    echo 'File copy: true' . "\n\n";
} else {
    echo 'File copy: false' . "\n\n";
}
```

When I try and run the script:

> Warning: copy(/home/site2/public_html/uploads/v2n62l6v.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/site2/public_html/move.php on line 15
>   File copy: false

I am trying to execute the file on site2. Any ideas why I would be getting a permission denied?

UPDATE:

When running a `ls -la` command on `/home/site2/public_html/uploads` I get this:

`drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2 12288 Mar 30 13:39 ./
drwxr-x--- 15 site2 nobody  4096 Mar 31 13:44 ../
drwxr-xr-x 10 site2 site2  4096 Feb 21  2019 0/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 1/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 2/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 3/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 4/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 5/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 6/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 7/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 8/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 9/
-rw-r--r--  1 site2 site2    25 Feb 20  2019 index.php`

Comment: do you have write capabilities for the folder?

Comment: @Mech permissions for the folder are set to 755.

Comment: *"Issues with moving files between two sites/accounts on server"* - Can you be specific as in what those sites are? Are they on different servers/domains? What are the values of `$site1` and `$site2`?

Comment: folders are naturally 0775 its who owns them that matters, which user runs apache?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, they are on the same server with different domains. `$site1 = '/home/site1/public_html/';` and `$site2 = '/home/site2/public_html/';`

Comment: Ok. Is that the actual full server paths? Maybe you missed something. Remember that all folders need to have write permission.

Comment: Also, make sure that all folders exist and that the names match what your syntax is. In \*NIX boxes, letter case matters. So `uploads` and `Uploads` are considered as being 2 different animals.

Comment: [*"Go to your Linux Terminal and use command sudo chmod 755 -R folder_name, if you are using VPS/Dedicated. if you are using Shared Hosting simply go to www folder and set permission by following given steps using UI"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47412133/1415724) - Is something I found on Stack. Did you/can you try that? Or try a relative path instead of full server/system path.

Comment: 1. Does `cp` work (without the PHP script)? 2. Please add the output of `whoami`. 3. Please also do a `ls -la` on the directory where you are copying the file _from_

Comment: @Evert `cp` did not work `cp: cannot stat '/home/site1/public_html/uploads/v2n62l6v.jpg': Permission denied`. Not sure what the permissions are now, prior to upgrading our cPanel/WHM this script work flawlessly. The `whoami` returned `site2`. Also, the ls -la did not work on the other directory. This was the error: `/bin/ls: cannot open directory /home/site1/public_html/uploads: Permission denied`

Comment: Alright that basically explains it. The files in site1 are not just read-only, they're completely inaccessible for site2. Maybe the permissions are 600/700

Comment: @Evert so even if I change my PHP to `copy('https://site1/uploads/v2n62l6v.jpg', '/home/site2/public_html/uploads/v2n62l6v.jpg')` and I have the `allow_url_fopen ` On, I am still getting the `Warning: copy(/home/site2/public_html/uploads/v2n62l6v.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/site/public_html/move.php on line 21` warning.

Comment: @zeropsi are you doing that with SSH, or via the web?

Comment: @Evert via web. I can try a wget via ssh or even a cp to test too. At this point, I may just chmod all the directories to 0777 during the migration and then set them back once done.

Comment: @Evert - after I change the directory on site2 to 0777 I have no issues with running the script and copying the files from site1 to site2. Sitting here scratching my head.

Comment: @zeropsi if you're doing it via the web, the webserver is likely *not* running as `site2`, even if the files are running from the `site2` public directory. It's probably `nobody`, `www-data`, `httpd` or `apache2` depending on your linux. The issue via SSH was because `site2` user did not have access to `user1`'s files.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the owner of the file is not the same user of your webserver, so folder permissions of 755 probably means read-only for your webserver.

You can set them to 777 but bear in mind that anyone/anything on your server can then write to that directory, or delete files from that directory.

Another option is to make the owner of the target directory the same user as your webserver is running as. (usually one of httpd, apache, www-data)

Comment: 777 IMHO, is a real bad idea. 755 is the usual setting on most servers. All the servers I worked on, had 755.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I agree, there is a risk. But it's about the same risk if the server is _primarily_ a webserver and these directories are owned by the webserver.

Comment: I think that the 3rd paragraph you wrote is probably what they should look into.

Comment: So the file I am using to execute the move is located at `/home/site2/public_html/move.php`. All of the folders and subfolders in the upload directory were created by the `move.php` script and all have 0755 permissions with each file having 0644 permissions. When I attempt to execute the script from http://www.site2.com/move.php that is when I get the Permission Denied error.

Comment: Additionally, if I attempt to execute via SSH with `php /home/site2/public_html/move.php` it still returns the same permission errors.

Comment: @zeropsi it's likely that 'site1' and 'site2' are different users. 644 means read-only for users other than the owner of the file.

Comment: @Evert. They are different users. However, the permission error is occurring on site2, who is the owner of the folders and files.

Comment: Yes, but how are you logging in with SSH?

Comment: @Evert - logged in with site2 user account.

Comment: Ok, can you share the output of `ls -la` of both the source and target directories? The ones that are important are the `.` entries and the files itself.

Comment: @Evert:  
``drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2 12288 Mar 30 13:39 ./
drwxr-x--- 15 site2 nobody  4096 Mar 31 13:44 ../
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 1/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 2/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 3/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 4/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 5/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 6/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 7/
drwxr-xr-x 12 site2 site2  4096 Feb 20  2019 8/
-rw-r--r--  1 site2 site2    25 Feb 20  2019 index.php``

Comment: Might be better to update your question to show all information you currently have. this is quite hard to parse. It might also be good to share the output of `whoami` just in case!